# How do I update my custom extension in Visual Studio without requiring it to be uninstalled first?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I have created a custom Visual Studio extension and have deployed via a internal Extension Gallery. When I make an update to my extension, it correctly shows up in Visual Studio *Extensions and Updates* as needing an update.

When I click *Update* and then *Install* on my extension, it gives me this error:

> The extension could not be installed because the following error occurred:
>
> My Custom Extension is already installed.

How do I update my custom extension in Visual Studio without requiring it to be uninstalled first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found my error: I did not update the version number in the `.vsixmanifest` file.

*face palm*

I updated the version in `AssemblyInfo.cs`, the `atom.xml`, but forgot the most important `.vsixmanifest` file.